# Separating by <br> tags in get_text()

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape text from a website while keeping its `<br>` tags for formatting my output with `'\n'`s. However, I can't find a way an efficient way to do so. (Note: I can't use `get_text(separator='\n')` because things like `<a>` tags will break it into awkward spacing.)

An example text I might be trying to scrape would be presented like:

```
<div class="example">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?
  <br>
  consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br>
  Vivamus nec <a class="someLink" href="example.com">arcu</a> 
  erat.
  <br>
  Suspendisse a mauris vestibulum, rhoncus.
  <br>
</div>
```

I know I could just have some code like:

```
def get_stuff(message):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read(), 'html.parser')
    example = soup.find("div", class_="example").get_text()
```

And it would get the text just fine. But again, I want to be able to format it with the `<br>` tags. I thought that `soup.find("div", class_="example").get_text(separator="br")` would do the trick, but there doesn't seem to be a way to use `<br>` as a separator in `get_text()`.

Is there any way short of specifically programming around the `<div>`, `<a>`, and whatever else there might be tags?

Comment: Using `.text` keeps the newlines and whitespaces in the text. Did you try that? Or, was that not what you were looking for?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Yes, that's not what I'm looking for though because it ignores the br tags which I want to replace with newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a recursive function which will return all the text including the `<br>` tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag

def get_text_with_br(tag, result=''):
    for x in tag.contents:
        if isinstance(x, Tag):  # check if content is a tag
            if x.name == 'br':  # if tag is <br> append it as string
                result += str(x)
            else:  # for any other tag, recurse
                result = get_text_with_br(x, result)
        else:  # if content is NavigableString (string), append
            result += x

    return result

html = '''
<div class="example">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?
  <br>
  <a>  text inside a_tag</a>
  consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br>
  Vivamus nec <a class="someLink" href="example.com">arcu</a> 
  erat.
  <br>
  Suspendisse a mauris vestibulum, rhoncus.
  <br>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
text = get_text_with_br(soup.find('div'))
print(text)
```

Output:

```
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet?
  <br/>
  text inside a_tag
  consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <br/>
  Vivamus nec arcu 
  erat.
  <br/>
  Suspendisse a mauris vestibulum, rhoncus.
  <br/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this. I appreciate the suggestion, but that still leaves me with all the other stuff I have to filter out though (like the <a> tags while still keeping their text) and I said I'm trying to avoid that and get only the text with br tags efficiently.

Comment: Have a look at the changed solution. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: I completely overlooked the `<a>` tag that you had in your example HTML, hence the naive first solution :)

Comment: The output is good, thank you for your answer! .. Unfortunately as I said, I am trying to solve this efficiently and I am really trying to find a solution that's a few lines within a function. I'd really hate to have to make a new function, import a new library, and throw a dozen lines of code on top of it.

Comment: I understand what you want, but, there's no new library import (hence no extra cost). Also, in terms of time efficiency, this is the fastest solution you'll get (at least that I can think of). But, yeah, it is not a straightforward solution like `get_text()`.

Comment: Hmm.. Fair enough. I'll keep looking, if I can't find anything then I'll label yours best answer. Thank you again for your help!